# How to set an ItemLongClick on a spinner list ?

Tags: android-spinner

I have a spinner and I want to do a long click on an item on my list but the OnItemLongClick doesn't work ...

Does anybody know the new way to set a long click on a spinner item ?

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

As per the android documentation there is no way to perform itemlong click on spinner item. Here is the [Link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html#setOnItemClickListener%28android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener%29)

So if you want to achieve spinner with on item long click you have to make a custom adapter and set long click on view.

```
public class TestSpinnerAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private String[] mArray;
public TestSpinnerAdapter(String[] array) {
    mArray =  array;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mArray.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mArray[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater =LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_spinner_item,parent,false);
    ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_name)).setText(mArray[position]);
    convertView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),"On Long Click",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
    });
    return convertView;
  }
}
```

And set this adapter to your spinner

```
mTestSPN = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spn_test);
    TestSpinnerAdapter testSpinnerAdapter = new TestSpinnerAdapter(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.array_name));
    mTestSPN.setAdapter(testSpinnerAdapter);
```

In string.xml

```
<string-array name="array_name">
    <item>Array Item One</item>
    <item>Array Item Two</item>
    <item>Array Item Three</item>
</string-array>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @praween05 !  But I don't know what adapter_spinner_item is ? In my example I have 3 spinners, can you give me an example of the adapter_spinner_item ?

Comment: Yeah its a xml file. Here is the code:-  
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/tv_name"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:padding="20dp"
          android:text="test"
    />

Comment: I still can't use this longclick with a simple click on my item ...It just gives me a long click on the whole view not my item